# how to access json objects in requirejs

Tags: javascript, json, requirejs

I have the following code, but can't seem to access the JSON objects from it using requirejs. I can access the objects using plain javascript(w/o requirejs). I'm just confused why it works differently with requirejs.

**rawdata.js**

```
define( function() 
    {
        raw = function()
        {
            return({"A":{"Asub":{"Asub2":100}}});
        }
    });
```

**myApp.js**

```
define(['./rawdata'],
    function(raw)
    {
        return
        {
            var retVal = raw.A.Asub.Asub2;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys. My bad. Looks like I just failed to add another return outside the function. So it should be:

```
define( function() 
{
    raw = function()
    {
        return({"A":{"Asub":{"Asub2":100}}});
    }
    return raw;
});
```

Anyway, I'd like to see other answers or better ways of implementing this. Thanks! :)